# XPages and Apache CXF: what's the best place for WSDL files?

Tags: cxf, xpages

I am currently testing Apache CXF (2.7.11). Purpose is to build a Web Service client. I am roughly following Martin Vereecken's blog post (http://www.bizzybee.be/2013/01/23/creating-a-java-webservice-client-in-domino-using-apache-cxf/#more-451). I have a WSDL file and I created sample code with the `wsdl2java` tool.

My first thought was to store the wsdl file in the NSF (e.g. *WebContent\WEB-INF\resources\wsdl*). However, the code generated does not seem to find the WSDL file. Code looks something like this (class name Session comes form the WSDL):

*Session.java:*

```
URL url = Session.class.getResource("WEB-INF/wsdl/twinfield/session.wsdl");
    if (url == null) {
        url = Session.class.getClassLoader().getResource("WEB-INF/wsdl/twinfield/session.wsdl");
    }
```

I tried both WEB-INF and /WEB-INF but neither seem to work.

If I put the WSDL file on the web (e.g. *domino/html/wsdl* folder) the url above works, but the code breaks later (it seems that it uses `java.io.File` trying to load the WSDL).

Local reference (e.g. *C:\temp\wsdl*) could work but does not really sound like a robust option.

The final java code will be in *WebContent\WEB-INF\src*, not in *Code\Java*.

So, what is the "best practice" for storing and referencing WSDL files in Domino environment?

### UPDATE

I went with @stwissel's proposal and noticed that the `wsdl2java` tool can actually create the whole jar for you. Just specify option -clientJar and the resulting JAR file will contain all class files + the wsdl file.

Comment: A robust solution will be to put your wsdl somewhere in your server e.g. in a folder where config files are, then add a system property for the location of the wsdl e.g. in the `server.xml` which you can then use in your webservice client. In this way you can use/reference the wsdl in whatever client you want. BTW I applied this approach in JBoss, I don't know for other environments.

Comment: Thanks, but the Domino environment is a bit different, there is no `server.xml` for example. The problem seems to be that neither `class.getResource()` nor `classLoader.getResource()` can find the WSDL file inside the NSF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate the Java classes from the WSDL, you should pack them into a JAR file. Put the WSDL into the Jar file, so it never gets lost. [This blog article](http://www.wissel.net/blog/d6plinks/SHWL-8SUKV5) and the comments explain it.

A potential issue could be the access rights (Java execution permissions) when you keep that jar inside the NSF.

The blog entry contains the sample code, so check it out!

Comment: I noticed that wsdl2java can actually create the whole JAR for you with -clientJar option. Seems to work OK. Added to original question.